# Receiving SSIS Error based on command line parameters

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

I'm currently migrating my DB from sql server 2005 to 2012. Part of that job is testing all the SSIS scripts as I go.
One of these packages works fine when I run it in the developer, however when I run it in a job, I get this error:

```
Executed as user: GLOBAL\sqlservicebanjo. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 11.0.6020.0 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.    Option " /CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING E" is not valid.  The command line parameters are invalid.  The step failed.
```

This is the commandline. Only difference is the server name and version:

```
/FILE "\"C:\xxx\yyy\zzz\list_List.dtsx\""  /CONFIGFILE "\"C:\xxx\yyy\zzz\listsconfig.dtsConfig\"" /CONNECTION "\"xxx.SSIS_Logs\"";"\"Data Source=zyz-xyz\BANJO;Initial Catalog=SSIS_Logs;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;\"" /CONNECTION "\"xxx.yyylogs\"";"\"Data Source=xxx-yyy\yyyy;Initial Catalog=xxxlogs;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;\"" /CONNECTION ListOneOffsGeneral;"\"c:\\"" /MAXCONCURRENT " -1 " /CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING E
```

Does anyone see any errors in the code, or seen this problem before?

Comment: Too lazy to mentally parse the command line options. If you bring `/CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING E` up after /FILE and its argument, do you get an error about a new parameter?

Comment: I gave it a try, getting this error now:
reserved.    Option """ is not valid.  The command line parameters are invalid.  The step failed.

Comment: For that example, string was 
This is what the string looks like:
/FILE "\"C:\xxx\yyy\zzz\list_List.dtsx\""  /CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING E /CONFIGFILE "\"C:\xxx\yyy\zzz\listsconfig.dtsConfig\"" /CONNECTION "\"xxx.SSIS_Logs\"";"\"Data Source=zyz-xyz\BANJO;Initial Catalog=SSIS_Logs;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;\"" /CONNECTION "\"xxx.yyylogs\"";"\"Data Source=xxx-yyy\yyyy;Initial Catalog=xxxlogs;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;\"" /CONNECTION ListOneOffsGeneral;"\"c:\\"" /MAXCONCURRENT " -1 "

Comment: Given that, my assumption is that something is bad with your parameters. Perhaps an incorrect escape sequence? Before I could resolve it, I'd need to identify what parameter is bad. How do I do that? I would do a binary search against the parameters. /file to the start of the /Connection. If that works, then I know the bad parameter is the second half. If that fails, then there's at least one bad parameter in the first half. Repeat until I've identified what's bad